# AndEngine draw line onSceneTouchEvent

Tags: android, line, andengine

I'm new to *AndEngine* and I want to draw a line by using my finger coordinates in the `onSceneTouchEvent` I did all what I knew and I think its right but there is something that keeps it from working I don't know what, I can't detect the problem :/

```
    private Scene scene;
float startX;
float startY;
float lastX;
float lastY;
int lineUsageCount = 0;

@Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
        switch (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            startX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
            startY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
            lineUsageCount = 0 ;

        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            lineUsageCount++;
            lastX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
            lastY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();

        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            if (lineUsageCount <= 5) {
                final Line line = new Line(startX, startY, lastX,
                                lastY, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

                line.setLineWidth(1);
                line.setColor(255, 255, 255);
                scene.attachChild(line);

        }

        break;
    }   
    return true;
    }
};
```

it should get the first coordinates `startX, startY` and then on the `Action_Move` it gets the `lastX, lastY` and draw the line but it doesn't seem to work :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is in this line of code: `if (lineUsageCount <= 5) {`
While you move your finger, `lineUsageCount` will be much more then 5. Debug this variable and than change it in "IF" or remove this "IF" from your code.

Comment: I removed the If and when I touch the screen the app crashes .. logcat: E/AndroidRuntime(28129): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread .. E/AndroidRuntime(28129): java.lang.NullPointerException @Racoon

Comment: seems you forgot to initialize scene: `Scene scene = new Scene();`